# rcu_dereference() vs rcu_dereference_protected()?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, rcu

Can any one explain what is the difference between `rcu_dereference()` and `rcu_dereference_protected()`?

`rcu_dereference()` contains barrier code and `rcu_dereference_protected()` do not contain.

When to use `rcu_dereference()` and when to use `rcu_dereference_protected()`?

Answer (score 8):

In short:

- `rcu_dereference()` should be used at **read-side**, protected by `rcu_read_lock()` or similar.
- `rcu_dereference_protected()` should be used at **write-side** (**update-side**) by the *single* writer, or protected by the lock which prevents several writers from concurrent modification of the dereferenced pointer. In such cases pointer cannot be modified *outside* of the current thread, so neither compiler- nor cpu-barriers are needed.

If doubt, using `rcu_dereference` is always safe, and its perfomance penalties (compared to `rcu_dereference_protected`) are low.

Exact [description](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/rcupdate.h?v=4.6#L758) for `rcu_dereference_protected` in the kernel 4.6:

```
/**
 * rcu_dereference_protected() - fetch RCU pointer when updates prevented
 * @p: The pointer to read, prior to dereferencing
 * @c: The conditions under which the dereference will take place
 *
 * Return the value of the specified RCU-protected pointer, but omit
 * both the smp_read_barrier_depends() and the READ_ONCE().  This
 * is useful in cases where update-side locks prevent the value of the
 * pointer from changing.  Please note that this primitive does -not-
 * prevent the compiler from repeating this reference or combining it
 * with other references, so it should not be used without protection
 * of appropriate locks.
 *
 * This function is only for update-side use.  Using this function
 * when protected only by rcu_read_lock() will result in infrequent
 * but very ugly failures.
 */
```